# Dividing two columns in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am fairly new to tableau and have a question about dividing two columns in my tableau workbook. In  the attached picture, numbers under in scope and out of scope programs, which are a group of a dimension themselves, are counts of respondents under the listed team leads in the Y axis.

I am having difficulty finding a way to divide the two columns to get a percentage or ratio. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

> [image]

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a "calculated field" to divide those two dimensions. Is your In and Out of scope dimension a field you made, or is that being pulled in with a query?

If it is something you made from tableau then just take the two measures you made it with and create a calculated field to divide them, then drag that pill back up to the columns bar.

If it is something you are pulling in with a query (meaning you cant separate the two) then you will need to look at your query to pull those two measures individually.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the pill CNT(Respondents) on the marks card that has the T (text) icon next to it. Choose Quick Table Calc -> Percent of Total

Right click on the pill again and bring up the "Compute Using" menu options. Try the options out to see how they behave. You can also go to the Analysis menu and turn on the row and column grand totals to better understand how "Compute Using" behaves.

Answer (score 0):

@Asfand

1. Create a calculated field (image for ref attached)

Goto -> Analysis -> Calculated field or click on down arrow (indicated) -> create calculated field.

1. Type  `COUNT([In-Scope Programs])/COUNT([Out of Scope Programs])`
2. Rename the calculation to In/out Scope programs or whatever you
   prefer.
3. Hit ok, that'll save the calc under measures.
4. Right-click the calculation: Default Properties -> number format
   -> Percentage.
5. Drag the calculation onto the text card.

[image: create calculated field]

[image: drag tha calc to canvas]